# remove dot from end of word in array using C#

Tags: c#

I have program that reads data from .txt file. I want to read only names that ends with letters `"ec"`. If that name has dot (.) in the end I want to remove it.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("../../file.txt");

    string data = sr.ReadLine();
    string[] words = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(' ');

    while(data != null){

        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++){

            if (words[i].Contains("ec")){

                Console.WriteLine(words[i]);
            }
        }
        data = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to display name that ends with letter e.
Also I have been trying to use something like this

```
if (words[i].EndsWith('.')) 
{       
    words[i].TrimEnd('.');
    Console.WriteLine(words[i]);
}
```

I have tried more way but I got lost.

Comment: Are you saying the word might end "e."? Your description isn't clear. Provide some sample data.

Comment: `words[i].TrimEnd('.');` - You didn't do anything with the return value from that.

Comment: If you don't want end of sentences, just replace all of the '.' in the strings with a space.

Comment: I have updated question. I want to display all names from my .txt file that are ending with `ec` letters. @AndyG

Comment: I'm still not clear. Do you want all words that end with "ec" or "ec.", then remove the dot (if there is one)?

Comment: I want the words that end with "ec" an then remove dot if there is one. :) @AndyG

Comment: If there is a dot after "ec" then it doesn't end with "ec". I would remove the dot's first then check for ending "ec".

Comment: Should you be ending up with a *new* collection of *only* those words that end "ec" (or "ec.")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the words that end with "ec" an then remove dot if there is one

You're doing the split only once before the loop, instead use:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("../../file.txt");

string line;
while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] words = line.Split(' ');

    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        string word = words[i].TrimEnd('.');
        if (word.EndsWith("ec"))
        {
            words[i] = word;
        }
    }
}
```

This approach first removes the dot from the end of each string, stores this into a local variable `word`. Then it checks if this word now `EndsWith("ec")`(dot already removed). If that's true this new word without dot will replace the old word in the array.

Comment: That would also catch "ec" when not at the end of the word(s), which the OP's code also suffers from.

Comment: @AndyG: i have just copy pasted the body of the for-loop from OP. I didn't know how that was related to the "remove dot from end" code. Hence i have added this to the end of my answer

Comment: @AndyG: OP commented now what he actually wants so i have edited my answer

Comment: Yes, I commented that "ec." doesn't end with "ec" ;). Trimming the dot first seems to be the solution (according to the OP's updates).

Comment: have tried your code but for me EndsWith in underlined :/ @TimSchmelter

Comment: @dome: Maybe you have used my first version which contained a typo `EndWith`. I have fixed that already. The method is [`String.EndsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable that the return value will populate:

```
if (words[i].EndsWith('.')) {

        string dotlessWord = words[i].TrimEnd('.');
        Console.WriteLine(dotlessWord);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will trim the character from the end of the string:

```
words[i].TrimEnd('.');
```

But it doesn't modify the string in-place.  Rather, like most (all?) string manipulation functions in C#, it returns the new string.  You just need to capture that modified value.  If you want it to be "in-place" then something like this:

```
words[i] = words[i].TrimEnd('.');
```

Or you could put it into a new variable instead if you like and then use that variable going forward.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *extracting* these names with a help of *regular expressions* and *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string[] words = File
  .ReadLines("../../file.txt")      
  .SelectMany(line => Regex         // In each line of the file
     .Matches(line, @"\b\w*ec\b")   // extract words which end at "ec"
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(match => match.Value))
  .ToArray();                       // if you want array as a final result
```

*Matching*, instead of *trimming* let you het rid of punctuation:

```
   ...
  'Quebec', we want the name only;
   ...
```

After `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words));` we'll get

```
   ...
   Quebec
   ...
```

Please notice both `'` and `,` removed. The implementation:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
  Console.WriteLines(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, File
    .ReadLines("../../file.txt")      
    .SelectMany(line => Regex         
       .Matches(line, @"\b\w*ec\b")   
       .OfType<Match>()
       .Select(match => match.Value))
    .ToArray()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To end-up with a collection of those words that end with "ec" or "ec." (as "I want to read only names that..." suggests):

```
string[] origWords = new [] { "here", "be", "words", "fooec", "barec." };

List<string> ecs = new List<string>();

foreach (string word in origWords) {
    if (word.EndsWith("ec") || word.EndsWith("ec.")) {
        ecs.Add(word.TrimEnd('.'));
    }
}
foreach (string word in ecs) {
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

---

```
// fooec
// barec
```